# error: reference to type 'const ItemInstance' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void'

Tags: c++, c++11, jailbreak, objective-c++, cydia

I tried to add a recipe in the iOS version of MinecraftPE, but I got this error. What should I do?

error: reference to type 'const ItemInstance' could not bind to an rvalue of type 'void'
  ..._inst->iteminstance(_inst, Item::mItems[432], 0), "###", "#S#", "###", d...
note: passing argument to parameter 'inst' here
void Recipes::addShapedRecipe(Recipes* res, const ItemInstance& inst, co...

The source code is here:

Tweak.xm

```
#import "../substrate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import <initializer_list>
#import <vector>
#import <map>
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import <string>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <initializer_list>
#import <vector>
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iostream>
#import <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include "Item.h"
#include "ItemInstance.h"
#include "Recipes.h"

ItemInstance* _inst = NULL;

void (*ItemInstance::iteminstance_)(ItemInstance*, Item const*, int);
void ItemInstance::iteminstance(ItemInstance* inst, Item const* item, int meta) {
    _inst = inst;

    iteminstance_(inst, item, meta);
}

void (*Recipes::addShapedRecipe_)(Recipes* res, const ItemInstance& inst, const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3, const std::vector<Recipes::Type, std::allocator<Recipes::Type>>& ress);
void Recipes::addShapedRecipe(Recipes* res, const ItemInstance& inst, const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3, const std::vector<Recipes::Type, std::allocator<Recipes::Type>>& ress) {
    addShapedRecipe_(res, inst, s1, s2, s3, ress);
}

void (*Recipes::_init_)(Recipes* res);
void Recipes::_init(Recipes* res) {
    Recipes::_init_(res);

    const std::vector<Recipes::Type, std::allocator<Recipes::Type>>& def = definition<Item*, Item*>('#', Item::mItems[296], 'S', Item::mItems[368]);

    res->addShapedRecipe(res, _inst->iteminstance(_inst, Item::mItems[432], 0), "###", "#S#", "###", def);
}

%ctor {
    MSHookFunction((void*)(0x1007569a4 + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)), (void*)&ItemInstance::iteminstance, (void**)&ItemInstance::iteminstance_);
    MSHookFunction((void*)(0x100781d74 + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)), (void*)&Recipes::addShapedRecipe, (void**)&Recipes::addShapedRecipe_);
    MSHookFunction((void*)(0x100774f40 + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)), (void*)&Recipes::_init, (void**)&Recipes::_init_);
    MSHookFunction((void*)(0x1012ae238 + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(0)), (void*)&Item::mItems, NULL);
}
```

Recipes.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "ItemInstance.h"

class Recipes {
public:
    class Type {
    public:
        Item* item;
        uintptr_t* block;
        ItemInstance inst;
        char c;
    };
public:
    static void (*_init_)(Recipes* res);
    static void _init(Recipes* res);

    static void (*addShapedRecipe_)(Recipes* res, const ItemInstance& inst, const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3, const std::vector<Recipes::Type, std::allocator<Recipes::Type>>& ress);
    static void addShapedRecipe(Recipes* res, const ItemInstance& inst, const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3, const std::vector<Recipes::Type, std::allocator<Recipes::Type>>& ress);
};
```

ItemInstance.h

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

#include "Item.h"

class ItemInstance {
public:
    static void (*iteminstance_)(ItemInstance*, Item const*, int);
    static void iteminstance(ItemInstance* inst, Item const* item, int meta);
};
```

Item.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Item {
public:
    char filler[200];
public:
    static Item* mItems[512];
};
```

Comment: The `...`s you copy hide the error. Is there an unabridged output somewhere?

Comment: What should I do? Fix your code presumably. You have a void method `ItemInstance::iteminstance` and you are passing the return value of that to another method call `res->addShapedRecipe()`. Since void methods don't have return values, this is an error. How you should fix it, I have no idea. Why were you trying to use the return value from a void method in the first place?

Comment: Aside: `const std::vector<Recipes::Type, std::allocator<Recipes::Type>>& def` should probably be `std::vector<Recipes::Type> def` or just `auto def`

Comment: The ```...``` is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the compile error, you need to pass `*_inst`, not `_inst->iteminstance(_inst, Item::mItems[432], 0)`.

This doesn't help you ensure you have populated `_inst` before `Recipes::_init` is called.

Presumably your definition of `ItemInstance` doesn't match the one your hook is intercepting, so your definition of `Recipes::Type` also doesn't match. Go find where these are correctly defined.